# How is the weight matrix set and its dimension in CNN

Tags: classification, multiclass-classification, confusion-matrix

I am trying to calculate the output size of each layer and the number of parameters for 3 class classification using CNN. I have calculated till the final maxpooling layer and would really appreciate help in understanding how to reach the fully connected layer.

In Matlab I checked that the size for fully connected (FC) is `1176` and the weights are `3*1176` I am struggling to understand what these 2 numbers mean and how they have been calculated. I could guess that `3` comes from the number of classes but how did `1176` come? It does not match my calculation.

**Question**: How to determine the dimension of the last layer- FC? Since I have 3 classes, do I have 3 layers? Please correct me where wrong. Attached is the screenshot which shows the dimensions for the weight as `3*1176` .

[image: img]

Comment: The number of neurons in your final fully connected layer is dependent on the number of classes you have, so you should have 3 neurons in the last layer. The number of fully connected layers after the convolutional layers is something you can decide for yourself.

Comment: How can I decide? As seen from the screenshot, Matlab is showing `1176` a number which I have no clue how it has come. It is shown as weights. So how come I have `3*1176` weights? What happens after the 4th step's calculation. These things are not clear to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 1176 is the number of neurons in the layer before the last layer, which is the number of pixels in the convolutional layer but flattened (`height*width*n_filters`, i.e. `7*7*24=1176`). The 3 comes from the number of neurons in the final layer, since you have 3 classes your final layer has 3 neurons, 1 for each class (which will output zero or one). This then gives a weight matrix of `3x1176` for the weights between the second to last layer and the last layer. Using `torch` we can show the dimensions of the data passed between the layers in the network. In the example below I have omitted the batch normalization and relu layers since they do not affect the dimensions. The dimensions are defined as follows: `batch_size * n_channels * height * width`.

```py
import torch

x = torch.randn(1, 1, 28, 28)
x.shape
# torch.Size([1, 1, 28, 28])

conv1 = torch.nn.Conv2d(in_channels=1, out_channels=12, kernel_size=3, padding=1)(x)
conv1.shape
# torch.Size([1, 12, 28, 28])

pool1 = torch.nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)(conv1)
pool1.shape
# torch.Size([1, 12, 14, 14])

conv2 = torch.nn.Conv2d(in_channels=12, out_channels=24, kernel_size=3, padding=1)(pool1)
conv2.shape
# torch.Size([1, 24, 14, 14])

pool2 = torch.nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)(conv2)
pool2.shape
# torch.Size([1, 24, 7, 7])

pool2.view(-1).shape
# torch.Size([1176])
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answering the question. I compared the sizes mentioned in your program & calculated by myself. Starting from the values at step 3) `conv2`  I start getting different results. Your code mentions the size as `14` but I got `20.5` i.e., `[20.5*20.5*24]` as the output from convolutional layer 2. The input is `14`. I am not getting `7` in the final step. If it is not too much for you, can you please let me know if I made mistake in the formula or something else??

Comment: I think you made a mistake in your calculation. Using the size of 14 from the first pooling layer and filling in the values in your formula gives the following calculation `(14 - 3 + 2) / 1 + 1 = 13 / 1 + 1 = 14`, which is equal to what is shown in my code.

Comment: Thank you very much!